# Memory Leakage during removal of an entry in concurrent hashmap

Tags: java, memory-leaks, concurrenthashmap

Lets say we remove an entry `<k,v>` from `ConcurrentHashMap`. The remove operation in `ConcurrentHashMap` will clone the nodes preceding the node which has to be deleted.

Now My question is how Java garbage collect the original nodes preceding the nodes which has to be deleted.

Lets say `1`--->`2`--->`3`--->`4`--->`5`--->`6` is a hashentry list which is maintained by `ConcurrentHashMap`. Now we want to remove `3`.

The following code is the code snippet of the remove method in Java `ConcurrentHashMap`

```
HashEntry newFirst = e.next;
for (HashEntry p = first; p != e; p = p.next) {
    newFirst = new HashEntry(p.key, p.hash, newFirst, p.value);
    tab[index]= newFirst;
}
```

- After 1st iteration

  `1`--->`2`--->`3`--->`4`--->`5`--->`6`

  `1A`--->`2A`--->`4`--->`5`--->`6`

  A new node `1A` will be created which will point to `4`. 
  The Original Node `3` is still pointing to node `4`. 
  Thus node `4` is pointed by 2 nodes
- After 2nd Iteration

  `1`--->`2`--->`3`--->`4`--->`5`--->`6`

  `1A`--->`2A`--->`4`--->`5`--->`6`

  The node `4` is a pointer to two list now (`1`--->`2`--->`3`) and (`1A`--->`2A`). The original nodes preceding Node `4` (`1`--->`2`--->`3`) are never removed from list of hashentries.

Ain't this is the case of memory leakage. How the GC will collect (`1`--->`2`--->`3`) as they are still being referenced by `ConcurrentHashMap` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misread that code a bit. First of all, the loop looks like this:

```
HashEntry newFirst = e.next; // the element after the deleted one, in our case: 4
for (HashEntry p = first; p != e; p = p.next) {
    newFirst = new HashEntry(p.key, p.hash, newFirst, p.value);
}
tab[index]= newFirst; // this is outside the loop
```

Secondly, this is a singly-linked list, so the iteration goes like this:

```
Step 0: tab[index] --> 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6
          newFirst ----------------------^
Step 1: tab[index] --> 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6
          newFirst --------------> 1A ---^
Step 2: tab[index] --> 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6
          newFirst -------> 2A --> 1A ---^
Step 3: tab[index] --> 2A--> 1A--> 4 --> 5 --> 6
                 1 --> 2 --> 3 ----^
```

*(Step 0 is the initial state, steps 1 and 2 are the two iterations of the loop and step 3 is `tab[index] = newFirst`)*

**As you can see, after step 3 there's nothing pointing to `1`, so it's eligible for GC and as a result, so are `2` and `3`.**

**P.s.:** Also note how the order of `2A` and `1A` is reversed in the new list. This should have no practical impact unless you have way too many collisions, but in that case the collisions themselves are a far bigger problem than the slight timing inconsistency this introduces.

Comment: ---> Thanks for quick assistance and Apologies for misplacing the '}' bracket of the for loop. Actually wanted to mention tab[index]=newFirst after for loop.

What I din't understand was how 1,2 and 3 will be garbage collected. But your comment  **bold "As you can see, after step 3 there's nothing pointing to 1, so it's eligible for GC and as a result, so are 2 and 3 **bold explained everything. Now I can understand how 2 and 3 become eligible for GC. Thanks a ton for really simple explanation.